# Advantages/Disadvantages of parsing data using initializer vs computed properties

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, properties, data-modeling

Let's say I have a json data object I would like to parse into an object of my own. I've came across two ways of doing this. The first is to use an initializer like so:

```
class DataModelOne {

   let firstProperty: String?
   let secondProperty: String?

   init(json: [Sting: AnyObject]) {
     self.firstProperty = json["firstProperty"] as? String
     self.secondProperty = json["secondProperty"] as? String
   }
 }
```

This would be called like so:

```
let object = DataModelOne(json: data)
```

where data is your JSON that you are trying to parse.

The second method that I have come across is by using computed properties:

```
class DataModelTwo {

 let json: [String: AnyObject]

 init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
   self.json = json
 }

 var firstProperty: String? {
   return json["firstProperty"] as? String
 }

 var secondProperty: String? {
   return json["secongProperty"] as? String
 }
}
```

This would be initialized in the same way as above:

```
let object = DataModelTwo(json: data)
```

Aside from the fact that you couldn't set the properties once the data has been cast using DataObjectTwo, as these are computed properties and so get-only, what are the advantages/disadvantages of parsing using these two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any real advantage to the computed properties. I prefer the first option, because:

1. This decouples your data model from the JSON. With the first option you can instantiate a `DataModelOne` without any JSON, and assign properties manually.
2. It's clearer because the parsing happens in one place.
3. You don't have to keep the dictionary around like you do with the computed properties. So if the dictionary contains a lot of other data that can be discarded, it can free up some memory.

The only advantage of the computed properties I can think of is that it delays accessing the Dictionary to the last moment. If you never access a property, it will never have to reach into the Dictionary in the first place. But the increase in performance will be negligible.

Lastly, I would rename the initialiser to something like `init(values:)`. You're not initialising it with JSON, but with a plain Swift Dictionary.